# Media module and views. Cannot make video image linked to node

Tags: entities, media

Using drupal 7.20,
Media 7.x-2.0-unstable7,
Media Youtube 7.x-2.0-rc2,
File Entity 7.x-2.0-unstable7,
Entity View Modes latest version.

Created new content type called "video", added video field type "Multimedia asset", Allowed remote media types "Video", Allowed URI schemes "youtube:// (YouTube videos)", "public:// (Public files)"

With Views 3 i am displaying Content: Video, File view mode "video_preset" (preset i created with Entity View modes module). But it only displaying an image, is there any working way to make that image a link?

Already tried "rewriting output of this field" thing, that not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the [File Entity Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity_link) module?  Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Out of the box, the Media and File Entity modules attach media to entities using Fields but they provide no way to then display media in those fields as links to the parent entity. A common use-case for this would be a teaser view of a node showing an image linked to the node.
>
> This very simple module adds an option to the "File Types" view mode settings to accomplish this (at admin/config/media/file-types/manage/image/file-display for images).

Comment: Thanks, but its not working for video field (media module)...

Answer (score 0):

I was using Mutlimedia Asset field type thats why file entity link didn't worked. So i changed my video field type to file -> media selector and link worked!

Answer (score 0):

@Heihachi [file_entity_link module](http://drupal.org/project/file_entity_link) worked for me...

I too was facing the same issue. This module is very simple to configure. You just need to go to admin/structure/file-types/manage/video/file-display/ Scroll down and next to Save button you have  **Link file to Referencing entity**.... [image]

Just click the save button and your video images would become linkable...!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [File Entity Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity_link) module, then the above answers will work. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Out of the box, the Media and File Entity modules attach media to entities using Fields but they provide no way to then display media in those fields as links to the parent entity. A common use-case for this would be a teaser view of a node showing an image linked to the node.
>
> This very simple module adds an option to the "File Types" view mode settings to accomplish this (at admin/config/media/file-types/manage/image/file-display for images).